# Why is my C++ Builder program so much smaller than my Delphi program?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

Today I downloaded the Delphi and C++ Builder XE trial.

I was worried about the size of Delphi exes for a long time (in XE it is 850 kb), and I thought, why such a big size of app even it is just has a blank form?

But on C++ Builder XE the minimum size is just 120 kb!
Even if I included a Delphi form in the C++ project, there was still no major size difference.

How is C++ Builder able to make a small exe with virtually the same contents? And why can't Delphi do it?

Comment: Sorry a little miss understanding thanks i did not check it by defout for c++builder build with runtimes was on

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe the C++ Builder exe you created is dependent on runtime packages such as vcl60.bpl and rtl60.bpl? This would explain the smaller size.

Comment: Delphi can do it too. The difference is that Delphi by default links runtime libraries where C++ does not. But you can disable runtime library linking in Delphi as well but then the program won't be able to run as standalone just like your C++ program above.